# update fail when id is in this format (2009-28-27389)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am having a problem when i try to update row in the database. the unique value i use to update is registration number which is in this format `(yyy-04-xxxx).`

```
if the registration number is like 2009-04-8374, the row is not updated.


but when the registration number does not contain "-" update works just fine.
```

Or do i need to do something when i insert row with a data in this format?

Or does digits containing  "-" have problems on update?

i am using PDO in mysql.
can anyone tell me how is this possible?

Comment: You are probably forgetting to _quote_ your _strings_ (casting them to number, nothing matches id -25408).

Answer (score 0):

There are NO *digits* containing "-". That's oxymoron.
A "digit" containing "-" is called "string".

So, you have to choose *string* type for your database field and use *string* type when binding value for the query. As simple as that.

Comment: sure. now you have to correct this mistake in your code

Comment: i will do that, is there a difference between varchar and string type?

Comment: varchar *is* a string type